# Is the bi-invariant Haar measure also invariant under any automorphism of $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, haar-measure

Let $G=\text{SL}(n,\mathbb R)$, a unimodular Lie group and let $\mu$ be a (the) bi-invariant Haar measure on it. Let $\alpha$ be any automorphism on this group. I wonder if $\alpha_*\mu=\mu$

By the unimodularity, if $\alpha$ is an inner automorphism (defined by conjugation of a group element) then $\alpha_*\mu=\mu$ by the bi-invariance. But what happens for general automophisms?

Comment: That's not even true for $G=\mathbb R$, is it? $\alpha(x)=cx$ is an automorphism, but it scales the Lebesgue measure by factor $|c|^{-1}$.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks! I will just focus on $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb R)$